# How do I invoke executable for Azure real time analytics?

Tags: analytics, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, near-real-time

My company has developed one windows analytics application. We have been asked to find ways to invoke this windows application so that we should be able to provide real time analytics using Azure.

Source for data can be either Azure event hub or Azure service bus or anything. We have installed this application in Azure VM but we have no clue how we will be able to invoke this application.

We have searched into Azure functions and Azure logic apps but could not find anything.

Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. You cannot invoke a plain Windows App / Executable located on a VM neither from Azure Functions nor from Logic Apps.
I guess you would need the application or parts of it hosted e.g. as Windows Service and then expose the invocation over HTTP as a REST endpoint. With that you would be able to call it from the above mentioned services.